# Finding the value of $[\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})+\cos^2(\frac{B+C}{2})] -(\cos B + \cos(A+C) )$ if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am new to trigonometry. I am stuck with this:

Assume $A$, $B$, $C$ are the angles of a triangle.

What is the equivalent of this?

$$\left[\cos^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\right] -(\cos B + \cos(A+C) )$$

Answer is $1$

Comment: what is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean evaluating
$$\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})+\cos^2(\frac{B+C}{2})=\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})+\sin^2(\frac{180-A}{2})=\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})+\sin^2(\frac{A}{2})=1$$
Further
$$\cos(B)+\cos(180^\circ-B)=0$$
So answer is $1$

Note:

I used
$$\cos(180^\circ-\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$$
and
$$\cos(\frac{180-\theta}{2})=\cos(90-\frac{\theta}{2})=\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$